# "Cut out" 3D Surface Plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I've created a 3d surface plot in R using persp() - though I'm not wed to that package by any means if something else would solve this problem better. My variables on the x and y axis, respectively, are temperature and precipitation. I've created a grid that extends from my min-max temp, and min-max precip, and predicted values from my function for the z-axis.

However, realistically, my data does not truly "extend that far" (i.e. I don't have data at the tails [e.g. a combination of the lowest precip and the lowest temp]) so the extrapolation is a little misleading.

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to "bound" my plot, and I'm open to many types of suggestions. I could color-code values that are out of the range of observed weather conditions, or if there's a way to "cut out" the surface, that would be great too. For example, I've found the "bounds" (e.g. the highest and lowest observed precip for each rounded temp value). I could use the bounds as a "jagged cookie cutter," but I have also fit a Gaussian-like curve using scatter.smooth() from which I think I can get a smoothed function to describe the boundary.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions; I'm finding a solution hard to come by but maybe I'm just looking in the wrong place. Thanks!

Comment: The Hmisc package has implemented a strategy for setting a "perimeter" object that it's plotting functions can access. It formerly worked with base graphics (including `persp`) but Frank Harrell switched over to lattice a couple of years ago so current versions work with the `bplot` call to `levelplot`,  `wireframe` or `contourplot`. The old code for a persp-call should still be available, though, if you look at the archives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `exclude.too.far()` function in the **mgcv** package, which was designed for the exact same plotting purpose you describe but in relation to 2-d splines.

An illustration of what this function does is given below, taken from the example of `?exclude.too.far`

```
library("mgcv")
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100) # some "data"
n <- 40 # generate a grid....
mx <- seq(min(x), max(x), length = n)
my <- seq(min(y), max(y), length = n)
gx <- rep(mx, n)
gy <- rep(my, rep(n, n))
tf <- exclude.too.far(gx, gy, x, y, 0.1)
plot(gx[!tf], gy[!tf], pch = ".")
points(x, y, col=2)
```

[image]

In the figure, the black points are the grid locations within 0.1 distance (after translating the grid to the unit square; so think of the 0.1 as being about 10% of the range of the data) of the observations, which are shown as large red points.

In the `persp()` setting, you have `x`, `y`, and `z`. Proceed as above to define the grid (the same grid that you used to create the `persp()` plot) and then use `exclude.too.far()` to identify which grid points lie too far from the data. Set the values in `z` to `NA` where `exclude.too.far()` returns `TRUE`. Then plot the modified `z` using `persp()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do your "cookie-cutter" approach, you could do something like this with the `sp` library and `point.in.polygon` function.  You would need the points specifying the perimeter you were interested in to contruct the polygon.

```
## Make some data
f <- function(theta) (1+1.5*cos(9*theta)) * (1+sin(theta)) + (1+0.5*cos(100*theta)) + (1+0.3*cos(50*theta))
x <- seq(-pi, pi, len=100)
dat <- data.frame(x=cos(x), y=sin(x)) * f(x)  # points for edges of polygon

library(sp)
d <- function(a, b) {  # density function to get z values
    ifelse(point.in.polygon(a, b, dat$x, dat$y) > 0, 1, 0)  # only points in range
}
ps <- outer(seq(min(dat$x), max(dat$x), len=100), 
             seq(min(dat$y), max(dat$y), len=100), d)
persp(ps, zlim=c(0, 3), theta=35, xlab="x", ylab="y", phi=25)
```

[image]